# Squeeze Theorem - limit of sum

Tags: limits

[image]

I've done part a but I'd like to check my algebra is right. Rationalising the denominator:

$\dfrac{n\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n^2+n}$

$=\dfrac{n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2+n}$

Divide through by $n^2 $ to get $\dfrac{1}{1}$

How do I then do part b?

Answer (score 2):

For the part a) what you did is fine.

For the part b): use the fact that
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} \le \frac 1{\sqrt{n^2 + k}} \le \frac 1{\sqrt{n^2 + 0}}
$$

Comment: I got to $\dfrac{\sqrt{1+1/n}}{n+1}$ - I don't see how that cancels down to 1 as n tends towards infinity... have I done it wrong?

Comment: on the LHS you have $\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$, and on the RHS $1$.